# Moonshine Apache Royal: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-royale, moonshine

Getting an error when trying to build a new project, right after it was generated.
Here is what I bee trying so far:

- changing `mxmlc` permission: `chmod +x`
- removing mac sandbox: `cd apache-royale-0.9.6-bin-js-swf` and then `xattr -cr .`

Error output:

```
: SDK path: /Users/goku/apache-royale-0.9.6-bin-js-swf/royale-asjs
: Sending to mxmlc: export ROYALE_HOME=/Users/goku/apache-royale-0.9.6-bin-js-swf/royale-asjs;export SETUP_SH_VMARGS="-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=en"; export ROYALE_SWF_COMPILER_HOME=/Users/goku/apache-royale-0.9.6-bin-js-swf/royale-asjs&& "/Users/goku/apache-royale-0.9.6-bin-js-swf/royale-asjs/js/bin/mxmlc" -load-config+=obj/CodeSearchConfig.xml -optimize=false -debug=true -o bin-debug/CodeSearch.swf -compiler.targets=SWF
: /bin/bash: /Users/goku/apache-royale-0.9.6-bin-js-swf/royale-asjs/js/bin/mxmlc: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Downloads!

Moonshine created a cool tool to help people just for this purpose: [Moonshine app store helper](http://moonshine-ide.com/moonshine-app-store-helper/) also called [Moonshine SDK installer](https://github.com/prominic/Moonshine-SDK-Installer). It is basically puts all the needed SDKs in your `/users/you/Downloads` folder, where Macs quarantine restriction is not applied.

---

BTW, unrelated to this answer, I ended up using feathers, and Royal, as it offer a much reacher components support.